# I am having trouble uploading and publishing my site on cpanel Namecheap

Tags: html, cpanel, website-hosting

I have changed all the html and css files to 0755 permissions and image files to 0644 permissions and the site will not publish. The files are all contained in the public_html folder and have no idea where to move on from here...

Comment: What is the error message which you are getting when you load the website on the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On their website they have something a little different:

The following permissions need to be set in order for your files to be displayed properly in the browser:

For all HTML and image files, the permissions have to be set to 644 (or 0644). They will be readable by all the user groups, but writable by the user only. These permissions are set automatically when the file is created.

Folders the permissions have to be set to 755 (or 0755). The folders will be readable and executed by others, but writable by the user only. These permissions are set automatically when the folder is created.

For all CGI files, the permissions have to be set to 755 (or 0755). The files will be readable and executed by others, but writable by the user only. These permissions are NOT set automatically once the file is created, you should adjust them manually.

[File permissions](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/400/205/file-permissions)

Comment: Would be helpful if you mentioned what kind of error you are getting, like a 500, 404, nothing, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, however, I have changed all my files on the public_html to 0644 (static website) and my website still hasn’t been published, there seems to be no change

Comment: If you have never set up your Namecheap account previously, the best thing to do might be to use their online support chat to ask what the problem is.  Could be all kinds of things, like your DNS configuation or other settings for your domain.  There should be a "Contact Support" button in your cPanel under Exclusive for Namecheap customers only.  You'll need your username and support PIN.  I forget how to get that from the cPanel, but you'll find it if you just login to Namecheap.com, upper left.